# angularjs : filter an array with a combobox

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I know how to filter an array with an input text as the filter. 
Is it possible to use the filter property of angularjs with a combobox as the filter options?

For example, I have an array of years: [2014,2014,2013,1987,1987]
I want to filter this array using a combobox with these values : {blank,2014,2013,1987}
In this combobox, if I click on blank, the array displays the initial values, otherwise it displays the filtered values.

The code below doesn't allow me to re init the array if I click on the first option of the Select tag :

```
<select ng-model="search.date" ng-options="year for year in years">
        <option value=""></option>
</select>
<table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Label</th>
          <th>Categorie</th>
          <th>Montant</th>
          <th>Date</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="budget in filteredBudgets | filter:search:strict">
          <td>{{budget.label}}</td>
          <td>{{budget.category}}</td>
          <td>{{budget.real}}</td>
          <td>{{budget.date}}</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not clear, why not sharing your html and coded app so far

Comment: my code :  `<select ng-model="search.date" ng-options="year for year in years"><option value=""></option>
 </select><br>  <tr ng-repeat="budget in filteredBudgets | filter:search:strict">....</tr>` sorry, i don't know how to go to next line with the short answer command.

Comment: you know you can edit your question and include there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that once you select the empty option, the modelValue becomes `null`.
Thus, passing the object `{date: null}` to `filter`, it will try to much items with `date: null`.

To satisfy this specific requirement of yours (i.e. treat a `null` value in `search` as if it was not defined at all), you could define a function that receives an item and (based on the `search` object) determines if it should be filtered out or not.

Then you can use that predicate function as an argument to Angular's `filter` filter.

E.g.:

```
<tr ng-repeat="budget in filteredBudgets | filter:filterBySearch">

$scope.filterBySearch = function (item) {
    return Object.keys($scope.search || {}).every(function (key) {
        var value = $scope.search[key]; 
        return (value === undefined) || 
               (value === null) ||
               value === item[key];
    });
};
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2jj56/)**.

---

A slightly more complex demo is available **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2jj56/2/)**. It allows a `strict` parameter to be passed to the predicate function.

---

**UPDATE**

An alternative approach would be to implement a custom directive (and add it to the `<select>` element) with the following functionality:

It will watch for changes in the model-value and convert any `null` values to `undefined`.
This solves the problem, because if a property of `search` has a value of `undefined` it is as if it is not there at all.

E.g.:

```
<select ... null-is-undefined>...</select>

app.directive('nullIsUndefined', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',   // <-- this is required for accessing the ngModelController
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (newViewValue) {
                if (newViewValue === null) {
                    newViewValue = undefined;
                }
                return newViewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/32ads/)**.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Between your two solutions is there a best(proper) one? or are they equal?

Comment: Both are "proper" (they get the job done and are Angularish enough). The second one is more slightly more efficient I think (especially as the items list grows), but you need to make sure you are OK with the fact that there will be no way to set your model to `null`.